# Get "a" value with highest frequency in (a,b) pairs, using sum(b) with smallest value as tie breaker

Tags: python, list

I have a python list of (a,b) pairs, and I would like to build a function which returns the a value with the highest count. If there are any ties, then sum the associated b values and return the a value whose corresponding b's have the lowest sum.

**Example:**

getMostFrequent([(1,3),(1,4),(2,5),(3,6)])=1

getMostFrequent([(1,3),(1,4),(2,5),(2,6)])=1 (because 3+4 < 5+6)

**My work so far:**

I have 2 functions, one which gets the highest count (no ties), and one which sums up b values for corresponding a values. I am having trouble combining them so that I can have a tie breaker, and then sum up the b values to break the tie.

```
lst=[twodlst[i][0] for i in range(len(twodlst))]
def most_common():
    return max(set(lst), key=lst.count)


def getAns(listofwinnersandconfidence):
    for i in range(len(listofwinnersandconfidence)):
        anschoice=listofwinnersandconfidence[i][0]
        d = {}
        for (k,v) in listofwinnersandconfidence: d[k] = d.get(k,0) + v 
    return min(d.items(), key=lambda x:x[1]) # Find min value, return corresponding key
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a dictionary to store `a` -> `[ count(a), -sum(b) ]`; then you can take the item from dictionary with maximum counts; I use `itemgetter` here instead of a lambda function. Notice that I negate the `sum(b)` so that the maximum of that value yields the minimum as you wanted ;)

```
from collections import defaultdict
from operator import itemgetter

entries = [(1,3),(1,4),(2,5),(2,6)]

counters = defaultdict(lambda: [0, 0])
for a, b in entries:
    # if a was not in dictionary yet, it will get 
    # initialized to a list [0, 0]
    counts = counters[a]
    counts[0] += 1  # count the a's
    counts[1] -= b  # count the 0 - sum(b's)

# items will be `[(1, [2, -7]), (2, [2, -11])]`;
# we take the [1] of them for key, thus we select maximum of
# [2, -7] and [2, -11]; then we take the [0] of the item
# tuple to get the key, i.e. a.
max_a = max(counters.items(), key=itemgetter(1))[0]
print(max_a)
```